# Can't redirect to Menu Ionic 5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing an app using Ionic 5, and after the user is authenticated, I want to redirect him to the page "accueil", which would contain a side menu.

I created the pages I needed, my auth page does work and redirected me the "accueil" page when I didn't have a side menu, but now it doesn't work anymore.

My `app.routing.module.ts` contains :

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
     path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' 
  },
  {
     path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
    },
  { 
    path: 'auth/:mode', loadChildren: './pages/auth/auth.module#AuthPageModule' 
  },
  {
    path: 'menu',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/menu/menu.module').then( m => m.MenuPageModule)
  }
];
```

Here's my `menu-routing.module.ts` :

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'menu',
    component: MenuPage,
    children: [
      { 
        path: 'accueil',
        loadChildren: '../accueil/accueil.module#AccueilPageModule' 
      },
      {
        path: 'profil',
        loadChildren: '../profil/profil.module#ProfilPageModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/auth/connect',
    redirectTo: '/menu/accueil'
  }
];
```

At first, the path of the redirectTo was :

```js
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/menu/accueil'
}
```

But I was having the error

```
"ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'menu/accueil'"
```

So I added `/auth/connect` to the path, but now when I log in the app, it doesn't redirect me anywhere. The url changes to `http://localhost:8100/menu` but the page doesn't load and there is no error displayed in the console.

Can someone explain me what I do wrong to implement a sidemenu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above method is to implement tabs and other children to a component such as maps.

for side menu you could use the following approach:

1. app.component.ts - create an array of objects that contain the different pages to your side menu.

   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
   import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
   import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
   })
   export class AppComponent {
     navigate:any;
     constructor(
       private platform: Platform,
       private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
       private statusBar: StatusBar
     ) {
       this.sideMenu();
       this.initializeApp();
     }
     sideMenu()
     {
       this.navigate=[
         {
           title : "Home",
           url   : "./home/home.module",
           icon  : "home"
         },
         {
           title : "Chat",
           url   : "./chat/chat.module",
           icon  : "chatboxes"
         },
         {
           title : "Contacts",
           url   : "./contacts/contacts.module",
           icon  : "contacts"
         }, 
       ]
     }

   initializeApp() {
       this.platform.ready().then(() => {
         this.statusBar.styleDefault();
         this.splashScreen.hide();
       });
     }
   }

app.component.html- add the ion-menu to your app

```
<ion-app>
    <ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" contentId="content1">
        <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>Navigate</ion-title>
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
          <ion-list *ngFor="let pages of navigate">
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="true">
            <ion-item [routerLink]="pages.url" routerDirection="forward">
                <ion-icon [name]="pages.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                   {{pages.title}} 
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet  id="content1"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

home.page.html - add the menu button to every page that you'd like the side menu appearing in.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>
        Home
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="ion-padding">
    The world is your oyster.
    <p>If you get lost, the <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/">docs</a> will be your guide.</p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

So you could redirect the root path to your auth page...then after auth simply navigate to home ( the page that contains your side menu)

To disable the menu on a given page..

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.page.scss'],
})
export class ChatPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) 
  {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false,"first");
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Note that in my app.component.html I have declared a menuId and not simply id....if you use id only there'll be no changes but with menuId the menu is disabled for that page

Comment: This was what I did before, but the problem with that approach is that even if I don't add the menu button to the auth page, I can access to the menu by dragging it. I think it is caused by the fact that the menu is defined in the app.component. I tried to disable it with the Menu Controller but it didn't work.

Comment: I've made an edit on my answer. You could try using the menu controller but with menuId instead of the plain id. if it works its way easier than the routing method

Comment: Glad to be of help!